# Proving that if $f :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $|f(x)−f(y)| > |x−y|$ and $f$ is surjective means $f$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Proving that if $f :\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $|f(x)−f(y)| > |x−y|$ and $f$ is surjective means $f$ is continuous.

I have the intuition that the only way this function *could* be discontinuous is if there is a jump discontinuity somewhere, something like:

$f(x)=2x $ if $x\ge0$ and $f(x)=2x+1$ if $x<0$

But then this function wouldn't be surjective on the reals. How would you go about proving this (somewhat rigorously)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $f$ is one-to-one and its inverse function is continuous.